# Object class with anonymous type constructor

Tags: java, object, anonymous, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

I am creating an Object as a  class variable with anonymous type. There are no compilation errors. My question is how to use the class? How to call the methods that I am defining? Where is it used actually?

```
public class MyClass {

    Object o = new Object(){
        public void myMethod(){
            System.out.println("In my method");
        }
    };

}
```

I am not able to call the `myMethod()` of object o. How to do that and when do we use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to call a method of an anonymous class that is not part of the super class methods is to call it straight away:

```
new Object(){
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("In my method");
    }
}.myMethod();
```

If you just store the anonymous class in an `Object` variable you won't be able to call its method any more (as you have figured out).

However the usefulness of such a construct seems quite limited...

Comment: Thank you. Got the idea. But still thinking the usefulness of this. If I have to call it straight away then what is the point of using `Object` class? Instead we can name it as a new class `MyClass` and use it later on to call `myMethod()` similar to as antonio pointed out using an interface

Answer (score 1):

To do something like this, you should be having a method in Object class. This in short means you need to override the method defined in Object class.

Try something like:

```
Object o = new Object(){
    public boolean equals(Object object){
        System.out.println("In my method");
        return this == object;//just bad example.
    }
};
Object o2 = new Object();
System.out.println(o.equals(o2));will also print "In my method"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable type is `Object`, so the only methods that the compiler will let you call are the ones declared in `Object`.

Declare a non-anonymous class instead:

```
private static class MyObject {
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("In my method");
    }
};

MyObject o = new MyObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void myMethod();
}
```

In your MyClass

```
public class MyClass {
    MyInterface o = new MyInterface() {
        @Override
        public void myMethod() {
            System.out.println("In my method");
        }
    };

    public void doSomething() {
        o.myMethod();
    }
}
```